# how to get all field names of a feature layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

i am trying to get all field names from feature layer from below link,
can you please explain me.

link:https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5

Answer (score 1):

https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5?f=pjson

Then deserialize json object to get the fields. For instance, by using JSON.parse( json_string ) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving this.
One woulld be to get the pure JSON representation of that service by calling:

https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5?**f=json**

And then examining content of *fields* array.

Other would be to initialize **FeatureLayer** objecy
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html 
and then examinig contetnt of object's *FeatureLayer.fields* property.

Then each of the items of those collections has a *.name*  property. Note that *Alias* might be someting different than what you are afer, so chose according to your needs.